# C++ Assigning value to attribute

Tags: c++

This may seem an obvious answer..but I'm trying to assign a value to my attribute.
IE:

```
class category{
private:
    string _starter;
    string _maincourse;
    string _pudding;
    string _drink;
    string _itemDescription;
    string _price;
public:
    category();
    category(string starter, string maincourse, string pudding, string drinks);
    void display();
    string tostring();
    //Giving value to attributes
    string _starter = "starter";
};
```

I'm trying to make _starter = "starter" same for the maincourse etc etc...however I'm getting an error saying "making _starter static" .

I also tried to do category(_starter = "starter"); which did not work either.

Comment: Put it in the constructor of class `category`.

Comment: So .. category::category() { string _starter = "starter" } ?

Comment: Yes, but without the type declaration (i.e., without the `string`)... Or as shown in the answer I gave below (`category():_starter("starter") {...}`). Or if you want the same instance of that attribute shared across all your `category` object, then just declare it `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the initial values as arguments to a constructor.

```
// ...
// constructor:
category
       ( const char * starter
       , const char * maincourse
       , const char * pudding
       , const char * drink
       , const char * itemDescription
       , const char * price
       )
       : _starter(starter)
       , _maincourse(maincourse)
       , _pudding(pudding)
       , _drink(drink)
       , _itemDescription(itemDescription)
       , _price(price)
       {}
```

Also, you can create accessor functions for your data items in the form:

```
 public:
     string& Starter() { return _starter; } // non-const accessor
     const string& Starter() const { return _starter; } // const accessor.
     // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the value of a member in the class declaration, you need to either declare it as static and define it in the definition (i.e. .cpp) file, or define it in the constructor.